# Why did German in South-Tyrol survive better than French in Aosta Valley?

Tags: languages, italy

The Italian regions of South-Tyrol and Aosta Valley have in common that although they're both part of modern Italy, they are, at least historically, places where the language spoken was not Italian. German speaking South-Tyrol was annexed from Austria-Hungary after their defeat in the Great War. As for (formerly) French-speaking Aosta Valley, they simply went in Italy per "accident" after the war of unification, because the French state "forgot" to claim the valley when they reclaimed Savoy and Nice in exchange of them helping Piedmont for the unification of Italy.

Needless to say Benito Mussolini has forcefully italianized those regions where, prior to the Great War, Italian was barely spoken, if at all. However resistance was high, and [Émile Chanoux](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89mile_Chanoux) sacrificed his life to defend the french-ness of Aosta Valley. After the war, both regions were granted extra autonomy and full bilingualism was introduced.

However it seems that, despite those measures, Italian largely supplanted French as a spoken language in Aosta valley to the point that some young people see French as an annoyance, or at best they'll speak it like a foreign, taught language. Apparently because the influence from the rest of the country, TVs and other mass media was larger than the influence of their own valley's history.

On the other hand it seems Southern Tyrol has largely retained its German-speaking characteristic and that it's rare to find native people of the region that'd actually speak Italian at home.

Is there any particular reason why there is such a large difference?

Comment: Two seemingly important differences: A) South Tyrol population is way higher than Aosta Valley, thus making interaction with other zones less frequent and B) Even assuming that Aosta Valley's original language was French (I do not know for sure), the Aosta Valley was part of the Duchy of Savoy that was incorporated into the *Kingdom of Sicily* (later *Kingdom of Sardinia*) in 1720, so it is likely that italianization started way before there than in South Tyrol. Note that the French "reclaimed" Savoy and Nice from the Italian kingdom of Piedmont.

Comment: SJuan76 according to a book I read Aosta Valley was virtually 100% francophone when it was annexed in 1868 and was only 4% italian speaking in 1914 at Great War outbreak (most Italians lived in Aosta city itself - the rest of the valley being exclusively francophone) (with the exception of 3 communes with some sort of Germannic settlement). The Italianisation really becgan with WW1 and Mussolini, so no significantly sooner than South Tyrol. The Kingdom of Piedmont was bilinguial, not Italian. (Savoy, Nice and Aosta valley were French speaking)

Comment: The word "seems" and unattributed opinions are doing a lot of work here.. Do you have any reputable source regarding attitudes towards languages? Maybe some polls? Or any solid comparison of language abilities in both regions? Anecdotally, I know some German speakers who were disappointed to find that South Tirol was far from universally German speaking.

Comment: I think this might be a question more suitable on [History.se]?